# Symbolic limit in Maple with assumption

Tags: maple, mathematical-expressions

Here I can't find the limit

limit(U0*(r^(n+1)-1)/(-1+r), n = infinity)

in Maple with condition |r| < 1 which is obviously -U0/(-1+r).

How can I tell Maple that abs(r) <1 so it automatically computes the limit.

P.S. I tried >assume(r <1); additionally( r> -1); but didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maple 15.01 (2011) or or Maple 16.01 (2012) I am getting,

```
limit(U0*(r^(n+1)-1)/(-1+r), n = infinity) assuming abs(r)<1;

                            U0  
                        - ------
                          -1 + r
```

I did not see the same behaviour for Maple 14.01 (2010).